# Online compiler causes crash when getting input from System.in

Tags: java

Receiving the following error code when using the online compiler (you can test the online codes here ->
http://tpcg.io/1Q93ObOJ)

```
$java -Xmx128M -Xms16M PassVerification
Please enter a new password.
Exception in thread "main" java.util.NoSuchElementException: No line found
    at java.util.Scanner.nextLine(Scanner.java:1540)
    at PassVerification.main(PassVerification.java:11)
```

[image]

The error I am receiving to my beginner knowledge is when the command nextLine(); is used it automatically skips over the user input. My question is how can I fix it so that it can read the user input and be able to run the necessary if and else statements to ensure the password that is being created is considered strong.

```java
import java.util.Scanner;

public class PassVerification {


public static void main(String[] args){
    Scanner run = new Scanner(System.in);
    
    System.out.println("Please enter a new password.");
    
    String pass = run.nextLine(); //crash occurs here.
    
    System.out.println("User input = "+pass);
 
    //trim codes for validating password, but unrelated to crash...
      
}
}
```

Comment: Kindly add some small code snipet in which you are facing problem rather than pasting the link of whole code

Comment: Add add stacktrace too

Comment: *"I have been receiving NoSuchElementException, which is caused when nextLine(); is not closed."* - That doesn't make sense.  That exception is thrown when you try to read a stream that has reached EOF.

Comment: try using  a different online compiler. seems like tutorialPoint's online compiler don't allow inputs from keyboard. e.g. https://www.programiz.com/java-programming/online-compiler/

Comment: @HectorCouzin, your code is working. you just need to enter your input in the STDIN tab in tutorials point online compiler before clicking on the "Execute" button

Answer (score 2):

It looks like the online java compiler you have used https://www.tutorialspoint.com/compile_java_online.php has the separate tab for standard input. Once added an input string in the stdin tab, the execution completes. Or alternative you can try below online compiler which has easy to read UI.
https://onecompiler.com/java/3wvzssxvd